# AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect Options not binding

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I am using AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect - http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/
the problem I am facing is the option attribute that is not binding to the model

```
        <div style="margin: 5%" checkboxes="true"
  ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model"></div>
```

For example:

if model is :

```
    $scope.example1model = [];

    $scope.example1data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"} ];
```

Issue:
the binding for **options** doesn't seems to work correctly as I am getting only **Id(s)** rest is working fine, if I check David and John ,the **options** binding with $scope.example1model  show only the **id** not the **label**
i.e : `[{"id":1},{"id":2}`
but what I want is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "David"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "John"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `externalIdProp` as empty string

```
$scope.extraSettings = {
    externalIdProp: ''
  };
```

html

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="options" selected-model="myModel" extra-settings="extraSettings"></div>
```

Works for me, I'm using `^1.11.8`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body>

 <div ng-app ="sortApp" ng-controller ="mainController">
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng-US">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <select class="multiselect" data-placeholder="Select Products" 
      ng-model="example1model" ng-options="item as item.label for item in example1data"
      multiple="multiple" multiselect-dropdown >
     </select>
  {{example1model}}
   <div style="margin: 5%" checkboxes="true" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model"></div>
 </body>
</html>
    </div>
 <script>
 angular.module('sortApp', [])

 .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.example1model = [];

    $scope.example1data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"} ];
 
 });
 </script> 

 </body>
 </html>
```